# Php no muestra el contenido de la taba de mysql

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

tengo un servidor remoto con mysql. Cree una base de datos con una tabla solo(todo muy sencillo, para ver como funciona). Escribo mi codigo php para poder acceder a mi base de datos ( con los datos de autentificacion bien puestos ) pero aun asi no muestra nada. Incluso haciendo echo al principio de todo. Aca les dejo el codigo

```
<?php
echo hola;
$HostName = "localhost";
$HostUser= "tt";
$HostPass= "enrique22";
$DatabaseName= "ejemplo";


echo "se cargo el archivo de configuracion"

if (!($iden = mysql_connect($HostName,$HostUser,$HostPass)))
        die("Error: No se pudo conectar con la BBDD");
if(!mysql_select_db($DatabaseName,$iden))
        die("Error: No existe la base de datos";

echo "estamos dentro de la base de datos";

$sentencia =  "SELECT * FROM employees";

$resultado = mysql_query($sentencia,$iden);
if(!$resultado)
        die(" Error: no se pudo realizar la consulta");

mysql_close($iden);


?>
```

Comment: Bienvenido, k1k4ss0. Cuando dices que no muestra nada, ni siquiera al hacer `echo` al principio de todo, te refieres al `echo hola;`, cierto? Te sugiero activar los mensajes de error de php, para que te informe qué está pasando (coloca `error_reporting(E_ALL);` al inicio de tu script).

Comment: vale lo probare muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Bueno opino que deberias empezar por utilizar el API mysqli...  por ejemplo:

```
<?php
   $link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");

   if (!$link) {
       echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
       echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
       echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
       exit;
    }

   echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database   is great." . PHP_EOL;
   echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;

    mysqli_close($link);
   ?>
```

Comment: vale probare poniendo eso